# The "Stack Overflow Comment Evaluator 5000" is (perhaps) failing to hide some usernames

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-evaluator-5000

I was just evaluating some comments and it would seem that usernames are not always being redacted with "@________".

See this -
[image]

So far I've seen two instances; both times the username was not at the start of the post.  Also the username may be typo'd as a search for the username from the image doesn't bring anything up (unless I'm not doing the search correctly).

Comment: I've seen this multiple times, along with usernames that just don't have the `@`, or where there's a space between the name and the `@`

Comment: How are the people that try the Comment Evaluator 500™ chosen?

Comment: Any link to this mysterious Comment Evaluator 5000? [edit: https://false-mammal.glitch.me/ ]

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier with a [sorting hat](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/the-sorting-hat).

Comment: (unrelated but) What's the button for "No longer needed"?

Comment: This is a terrible way to evaluate comments, holy crap. Evaluators should be required to write a text response describing their evaluation of each comment.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier They had to have opted in to survey/contact requests from SO the company and get lucky, or be a moderator.

Comment: *Cue the meta posts regarding the new evaluator*

Comment: @TylerH Trust me, there have been plenty of comments where I'm like, "Well, it's not rude or disrespectful or anything, but God is this comment useless." The options we're given are definitely not always the best way to categorize. A text box to give thoughts definitely would've been better, at least in addition to the buttons.

Comment: @Kendra At the very least, all the same options as we currently have for flags should be available (e.g. "no longer needed" should be added ), the comments should be displayed in context of the post, with users attached (dummy users 1 and 2, etc., if they care about skewing results based on familiarity), and a summary text box a la the 'something else' flag should be required for each page so that the participants can provide context and reasoning for why they reviewed the comments the way they did. Also replacing meaningful information with emojis is atrocious and shame on SO for doing that.

Comment: I'm wondering why they never used the actual flag reasons. It'd make more sense. This just seems like nonsense and not inline with the sort of thing SE / SO does. How do those emojis actually convey the correct opinions? It'd be a more accurate data set too.

Comment: @TylerH Afaik it's not meant to truly evaluate comments. It's meant as a dataset to train models and run interesting queries against

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth And there's the underlying problem. Before we can train computers to do anything useful we need humans to understand what is being put into the computers.

Comment: @user202729: There isn't one. A comment's contextual relevance has no bearing on its (either intended or perceived) tone.

Comment: @BoltClock what about in the instance that user A asks OP a question to clarify then notices that this is already addressed in the post and then deletes it and in the mean time OP or someone else answers the question in the comment without noticing that it has been deleted. On the outset the answer may contain relevant information but in actual fact, it is no longer needed.

Comment: @Script47: Notice how nowhere in your question you mention the tone of either of those comments. Again, whether a comment is contextually relevant doesn't matter. The tool is intended for evaluating a comment's perceived tone, not whether it's still needed (and you wouldn't be able to know anyway given that every comment is shown to you devoid of any context whatsoever). If that remaining comment is helpful or friendly, it's "Fine." If it's snarky, it's "Disrespectful or Unfriendly." And if it calls the other person names or their background into question, then it's "Abusive or Harassment."

Comment: I also found some comments that had a working edit link in them

Comment: @BoltClock I disagree that *"A comment's contextual relevance has no bearing on its... tone"*. It only took me a couple of clicks to hit a case where lack of context stopped me from knowing if I thought a comment was "disrespectful" - a comment instructing the asker to *"Try to post your code which you have tried"*. If it was a debugging question where that information was needed, the comment is fine. If the information was plainly not needed, it's disrespectful - then the commenter is being petty and officious and trying to shoot down a valid question. I don't know which is true.

Comment: @BoltClock Another example: *"Thanks, do you also know how I could make those rounded corners?"*. Was making those rounded corners part of the original question? If so, pointing out that an answer missed it is fine. If not, latching on to somebody who answered the original question as posed and trying to make them answer further unrelated questions for you in the comments is classic Help Vampire behaviour, which we've communally agreed is disrespectful. Without context, I can't classify.

Comment: @MarkAmery While working on these, we're supposed to be treating them as if we were a brand new user, arguing we might not know that community standard. =/ It's supposed to be entirely based on tone. (Of course, I've only had a handful that were "Disrespectful" and one "Abusive" so far, so... I'm probably still more positive than some new users.)

Comment: @Kendra Eh, I've done a few dozen now and all of them have either been "Fine" or me deciding not to classify and refreshing because of the lack of context problem described above. I think non-fine comments are genuinely unusual in whatever sample these are being drawn from.

Comment: @Mark Amery: You're right, I don't know what I was going on about with my second sentence. I think my reply to Script47 does a better job explaining what I meant to say (that the tool isn't meant for evaluating whether a comment is chatty or otherwise unnecessary for reasons *other than* its perceived level of friendliness).

Comment: @tylerh (yes I agree but) Who will spend the time to read it?

Comment: @user202729 One must assume the people creating this project and asking this time of volunteers will actually follow through with it and read them.

Comment: @TylerH I've been saying that it looks exactly as if the company thought that new users are stupid. It's only fair for them to assume that everyone else involved in the welcoming initiative is stupid too, so better keep it simple. Smiley face, unwelcome face, angry censorship face. The more knee-jerk the reaction the better.

Comment: And special char like ç break the annonmisation.

Answer (score 22):

Yeah you pretty much nailed it. We couldn't reliably redact @names when they occurred in positions other than the start of the string. There were a lot of non @name usages of @ when it appeared later in the comment. We erred on the side of not wrecking the understandability of those comments by applying an ill-suited regex, so these @names still remain.

Comment: Status-workswellenoughsowontfix?

Comment: I guess not posting any of the comments we get to see is part of the terms of using the comment evaluator that came with the email?

Comment: @Magisch Correct: "We will emphasize the sensitive nature of this data and ask requesters to respect Stack Overflow users’ privacy by not publishing individual comment texts."